Defining the Intersection of a n-simplex and a hyperplane in $\mathbb R^n$.
I am trying to consider the intersection between a n-simplex and a hyperplane. Other results (on here and on other sites) have confirmed my claim that the hyperplane intersects in (at most) $\frac{n^2}{4}$ or $\frac{n^2-1}{4}$ isolated points (along 1-faces). My concern is how to describe this shape. Various resources show that the intersection of two convex shapes is convex, which is the case here, but is there any way to show that the intersection is a convex hull of exactly these (at most) $\frac{n^2}{4}$ points?
Thanks

Can you clarify? If I intersect a line with a 2-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it either intersects in a single point or two points and the line segment between them. In the second case, 2 (the number of endpoints) is larger than $n^2/4$.

@JohnPalmieri sorry, you are correct. It should be $\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$. I confused the dimension of the simplex with the number of vertices. This is the maximum of $a\cdot b$, where $a+b=n+1$, which comes from all the ways of partitioning the $n+1$ vertices.
